# Whitelist Application For Windows Server 2012

Tags: authentication, windows, server, whitelist, blacklist

### My problem

I am looking for an application which runs on **Windows Server 2012** for security reasons. Our server began attacked on many protocols. They are trying brute force attacks with very weak passwords. It is just annoying and just slowes down the server.
So we decided to use Blacklisting programs (after 3 tries it creates a firewall entry for it's IP) but we want a better solution.

### So, I need a program which provides these functions:

- Diables every ports except *80*, *443* etc. and one for a **custom authentication** method
- **Runs a port** for authenticating the team members (*developers*, *testers* etc.) with a **custom method** which is *not popular enough for hacking*
- After successful authentication it would **open each port** that is required for the user to work just **for it's IP**.
- Keeps wathing when the IP **address of authenticated users changes**. It's because of **home office** workers.

### My questions are:

- Is it worth at all to change Blacklist to Whitelist?
- Could you suggest me some solutions that are already exists?
- Is it a good idea to program it by myself?

Comment: I think you are looking for a VPN to allow access for authorised people and a firewall to block all ports.

Comment: Sadly no. I need to block all of the ports except of some services (web servers and some app server used by clients) plus one for this authentication. So attackers can't try to break NTLM, Database, GIT etc. Only one can access these who already authenticated itself this custom way.

Comment: None of your comment means that a VPN is not the solution. I'm not sure you understand how a VPN is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: So you mean, that the ports only the team members are using should be accessible on a private network throught VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it worth at all to change Blacklist to Whitelist?

Possibly. Whitelists are nearly always better but hard to say for sure from what you've said.

> Could you suggest me some solutions that are already exists?

I'm a little confused here. The "best" solution to this problem is nearly always a dedicated firewall. Is there a reason you are not using that?

You really need to give us some more information about the server and what it is doing and in what environment. As others have commented, a VPN might be the best solution for your developers and admins.

> Is it a good idea to program it by myself?

No! It is never a good idea to do that. You will never have the level of resources available to people and organisations who's sole purpose is to produce security solutions.